# Python - replace list item if substring characters are equal

Tags: python, replace, psychopy

I am creating a list containing images randomly sampled from a large master list. I am trying to replace any item in 'image_list1' with a new, randomly selected image if a range of characters is equal.

Example:

'AF05_AC.png'

'AF05_AO.png' <- replace since characters [0:5] are equal to image above

Not sure how to implement this since I don't want to replace it with a specific value, but keep sampling until n=20 without that range of characters being equal for any item in the list.

```
with open('Faces/negFaces.txt') as f:
    negFaces= f.read().splitlines()

   n=20
   image_list1 = random.sample(negFaces, n)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there a particular reason you want to randomly sample? If not, then you can create buckets based on the substring. Then for each bucket, select a maximum of one image. For example, 'AF05_AC.png' and 'AF05_AO.png' would both go into the bucket of 'AF05_A'. In this way, you could randomly select a bucket and then randomly select a string from that bucket, but this would introduce a bias based on the number of images in each bucket.

If you really want it to be perfectly random, then I can't think of anything other than brute forcing it until your condition is satisfied, although depending on the substring and images, this could take a very very long time, or could even result in an infinite loop if you're not careful. I'm generally bad at probability though so there might be a way to accomplish this with perfect randomness.

Comment: I'm creating this list for an experiment, so I need it to be made up of images randomly selected from the master list. The images with matching substrings are slightly different, but close enough that it needs to be controlled so that they don't ever occur in the same list.

Comment: So then the bucket solution works for you I'm guessing.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to help others. For formatting, please use a star, double star, or a tick to wrap pieces of code, and not single or double quotes. Eg: `AF05_AC.png`.